# Material-ui tooltip not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the material-ui tooltip. I want the tooltip to be displayed at the top. 
Even after setting `placement="top"`
The demo can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yjrq3lkk29)

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: For `touch` event for `mobile`, see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70270694/984471

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because page has not enough space to show tooltip on top position
Just add simple padding then try it again.

```
<div style={{padding: '50px'}}>
  <Tooltip placement="top" title="Chart Type">
    <IconButton >
      <ShowChart />
    </IconButton>
  </Tooltip>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a form wrapper, the outlined variant contains a "pointer-event: none" property that would prevent the popover from getting any events.