# Material ui tooltip is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Tried converting Tooltip to a controlled component which depends on onClick event
This works fine in mobile and web but it looses it's original behaviour to show Tooltip on hover
Is there a solution that makes Tooltip work both on hover and onClick

Comment: Please, specify your question more clearly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 73):

As part of styling
Wanted to have `touch` event for `mobile`
Wanted to have `hover` event for `desktop` to also work

But had difficulty making it working due to `hover` for mobile.

Making `enterTouchDelay` value to `0` worked on mobile, `700ms` is default value:

```js
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

<Tooltip title="Some message" enterTouchDelay={0}>
  <Button>Some message</Button>
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: Furthermore, you can use `leaveTouchDelay` (default value: 1500ms) in order to make the tooltip persistent (e.g. `leaveTouchDelay={5000}`. This is useful if you have a long tooltip text to show.

Comment: I don't know why this is not a default correct answer. It should be.

Answer (score 7):

**So ultimately we need a tooltip that works both on hover and onClick.**

Default Material-UI tooltip works fine both on web and mobile.

```
<Tooltip title="Show Tooltip">
   <Button>Long press for 1s to show tooltip on mobile</Button>
</Tooltip>
```

Long-pressing on mobile shows tooltip but it also opens the dailog box which opens when we right-click(ctrl + click on mac) on web. So it is not UX friendly.

So enabling onClick by not loosing the hover functionality is ideal for both web and mobile devices.

```
  <Tooltip
    title="I am tooltip"
    open={showTooltip}
    onOpen={() => setShowTooltip(true)}
    onClose={() => setShowTooltip(false)}
  >
    <Button
      variant="outlined"
      color="primary"
      onClick={() => setShowTooltip(!showTooltip)}
    >
      Hoverme to open Tooltip
    </Button>
  </Tooltip>
```

[Click here for complete code snippet.](https://codesandbox.io/s/sof-material-ui-tooltip-jz26n?file=/src/StackOverFlow.js)

Answer (score 3):

For mobile, the click solution seems the best.

The docs provides one example with it,

```
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleTooltipClose}>
        <div>
          <Tooltip
            PopperProps={{
              disablePortal: true,
            }}
            onClose={handleTooltipClose}
            open={open}
            disableFocusListener
            disableHoverListener
            disableTouchListener
            title="Add"
          >
            <Button onClick={handleTooltipOpen}>Click</Button>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
      </ClickAwayListener>
```

https://mui.com/components/tooltips/#triggers